# Map display not centered and showing zoomed out

Tags: javascript, leaflet

My team tried to integrate the maps and everything looked good but the location of the pointer always comes either on top right/top left, i.e. it is not showing in the center. Also, the map results based on searched locations are very zoomed out. The videos I saw on leaflet tutorials showed coding to reflect map pointers on the center and relatively zoomed in. Attaching an image to understand my issue clearly and also an image to show what exactly I am looking for from this question and how exactly I want the map should look like from the search

[image]

I would really appreciate the help and guidance on this one.

Tried what was mentioned in the tutorial videos and was expecting a result similar to this.

[image]

Comment: I believe this website is more about helping you with code you have written, rather than writing code for you. It appears to me that you are asking for someone to post sample code for a "maps" website. Hence I suggest that you [edit] your question and post your code (preferably a [mcve]) and hopefully someone will be able to help you with that code.